# IFrame OnReadyStateChange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser

I have an asp.webforms application and on page a i have a hidden div with progressbar and iframe. To iframe i try loaded form from another application on same domain.

```
<div id="pagePreview" style="display: none;">
            <div class="progressBarWrapper" id="waitDialog" style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);display:none;">
                <div class="progressBarDetail" style="margin-top:25%;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgLoading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/wait.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <iframe id="previewContent" onreadystatechange="iframeLoaded(this);"></iframe>
        </div>
```

On a click event i call a function to show this div in jqueryUI dialog and i Want show progressbar until the page in Iframe is not loaded.

```
var isClickedForDialog = false;

function iframeLoaded(args) {
            if (args.readyState == "complete" && isClickedForDialog) {
                var pagePreview = $('#pagePreview'); // dialog
                var waitDialog = $('#waitDialog'); // progress

                waitDialog.hide();

                isClickedForDialog = false;
            }
        }

function showModalWindow(url, hideCloseButton) {
            isClickedForDialog = true;

            var previewContent = $('#previewContent'); // Iframe
            var pagePreview = $('#pagePreview'); // dialog
            var waitDialog = $('#waitDialog'); // progresss

            waitDialog.show();

            previewContent.attr('src', url); 

            pagePreview.dialog(
                    {
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 764,
                        width: 1020,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            previewContent.attr('src', '');
                        },
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            if (hideCloseButton) {
                                $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

In IE everything works fine. The dialog box and progressbar displays and when the URL is loaded in an iframe, progressbar disappears and i see only webforms in IFrame.

But in FireFox and Chrome this does not work.

The browser ignores the onreadystatechange event. I tried to handle an event as following:

```
$('#previewContent').bind('onreadystatechange', iframeLoaded, false); 
$('#previewContent').on('onreadystatechange', iframeLoaded);
```

but without success.

know how to solve this? thanks

Comment: Use the load event. Why is there a space here? `$('# previewContent')`

Comment: the space was typing error...

Comment: Kevin B: you're right. In Firefox and Chrome load event helped. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's some specific reason why you're using onreadystatechange, but if you just want to know when the iframe is done loading, the load event will handle that.

```
$('#previewContent').on('load', iframeLoaded);
```

Comment: I wanted use onreadystatechange to detect if iframe is fully loaded.
Is interesting that it works in IE but not in other browsers

Comment: It seems to be a proprietary thing to IE. I don't see any reference to that outside of the msdn. The msdn also doesn't link to any specs related to it.

Comment: If the frame does not load this event will not be fired in Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `onreadystatechange` attribute to an `iframe` tag as shown in the original question doesn't seem to do anything. **Don't** do this:

```
<iframe onreadystatechange="iframeReady(this);"></iframe>
```

Instead, grab a reference to the `iframe` element and add a `DOMContentLoaded` listener to its `contentDocument` property. Since your `iframe` might already be fully loaded, you should check its `contentDocument`'s `readyState` and cancel the listener if the `iframe` isn't loaded yet. Finally, some browsers - namely Firefox - don't currently emit a `DOMContentLoaded` event from iframes, so for a fallback you could add a `load` listener on the `iframe`'s `contentWindow` property, or the iFrame itself.

```
function listenForIframeReady() {
  if (iframe.contentDocument.readyState === "interactive" || iframe.contentDocument.readyState === "complete") {
    iframeReady();
  } else {
    iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', iframeReady);
    iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('load', iframeReady);
    iframe.addEventListener('load', iframeReady);
  }
}

function iframeReady() {
  console.log('iframe is ready');
  iframe.contentDocument.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', iframeReady);
  iframe.contentWindow.removeEventListener('load', iframeReady);
  iframe.removeEventListener('load', iframeReady);
}

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
listenForIframeReady();
```